# Distance internationalization in Javascript

Tags: javascript, internationalization, distance

I can't seem to find any internationalization library in Javascript that handles distances/lengths. I was looking for one that would display/convert distances according to the region: meters for *en-CA*, miles for *en-US* etc...
I'm relying on **Intl** for currencies, **i18next** for translations, **moment** for dates, but didn't find any for distances (nor for weights or volumes).

Among the reasons of using a library rather than doing it myself:

- to limit the code adjustments when introducing a new region
- to display decimals/grouping commas in a standard way if necessary
- maybe some units are preferred to others below some distances

Would there be a library that I missed?

Comment: you can use the unit option of the intl api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat, and also use it via i18next: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting